# In C#, what is the best way to find out if a class has a property (using reflection)

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class

```
 public class Car
 {
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public int Year {get;set;}
 }
```

In seperate code, i have a field name as as string (let use "Year") as an example.

I want to do something like this

```
   if (Car.HasProperty("Year"))
```

which would figure out if there is a Year field on the car object.  This would return true.

```
   if (Car.HasProperty("Model"))
```

would return false.

I see code to loop through properties but wanted to see if there was a more succinct way to determine if a single field exists.

Comment: Wouldn't `HasProperty` be a better method name?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This extension method should do it.

```
static public bool HasProperty(this Type type, string name)
{
    return type
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Any(p => p.Name == name);
}
```

If you wanted to check for non-instance properties, private properties, or other options, you can tweak the `BindingFlags` values in that statement. Your usage syntax wouldn't be exactly what you give. Instead:

```
if (typeof(Car).HasProperty("Year"))
```

Answer (score 9):

Since you seem to be looking only for `public` properties, [Type.GetProperty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx) can do the job:

```
if (typeof(Car).GetProperty("Year") != null) {
    // The 'Car' type exposes a public 'Year' property.
}
```

If you want to further abstract the code above, you can write an extension method on the `Type class`:

```
public static bool HasPublicProperty(this Type type, string name)
{
    return type.GetProperty(name) != null;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
if (typeof(Car).HasPublicProperty("Year")) {
    // The 'Car' type exposes a public 'Year' property.
}
```

If you also want to check for the presence of non-`public` properties, you will have to call the override of [Type.GetProperties()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) that takes a `BindingFlags` argument, and filter the results as David M does in his answer.